# How to get an authorized PHAsset from UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, phasset

I have this code:

```
@IBAction func importButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        self.imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        self.imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String, kUTTypeImage as String]

        self.present(self.imagePicker,animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This presents the UIImagePicker perfectly. Then when I want to use the picked item to get say the date of the PHAsset:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        guard info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] != nil else { return }
        let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! CFString
        switch mediaType {
        case kUTTypeImage:
            if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
                ...
            }
            break
        case kUTTypeMovie:
            if let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? URL, let pickedAsset = info[UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset] as? PHAsset {
                print("kUTTypeMovie")
                MyVariables.isScreenshot = false
                let creationDate = pickedAsset.creationDate
                print(creationDate,"creationDate")
            }
            break
        case kUTTypeLivePhoto:
            print("livePhoto")
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

            break
        default:
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

            print("something else")
            break
        }
    }
```

Now, when I pick a video for instance,`print("kUTTypeMovie")` fails I think because `let pickedAsset = info[UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset] as? PHAsset` fails

Elsewhere ([UIImagePickerControllerDelegate get date from picked image in iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47316909/uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate-get-date-from-picked-image-in-ios-11)) I have seen that perhaps this is because I need authorization to pick PHAssets.

So I change my first block of code to:

```
@IBAction func importButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        let status = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()

        switch status {
        case .authorized:
            PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({status in
                if status == .authorized {
                    self.imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                    self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
                    self.imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String, kUTTypeImage as String]

                    self.present(self.imagePicker,animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            })
        case .denied:
            print("denied")
        // probably alert the user that they need to grant photo access
        case .notDetermined:
            print("not determined")
        case .restricted:
            print("restricted")
            // probably alert the user that photo access is restricted
        }

    }
```

However now when I press the import button it crashes with an lldb error:

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__abort_with_payload:
    0x1854f7040 <+0>:  mov    x16, #0x209
    0x1854f7044 <+4>:  svc    #0x80
->  0x1854f7048 <+8>:  b.lo   0x1854f7060               ; <+32>
    0x1854f704c <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x1854f7050 <+16>: mov    x29, sp
    0x1854f7054 <+20>: bl     0x1854d8bdc               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x1854f7058 <+24>: mov    sp, x29
    0x1854f705c <+28>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
    0x1854f7060 <+32>: ret
```

So clearly I am not doing that correctly. How am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crash is because of the below missing permission to access the photo library,

> This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

In your `Info.plist`, add `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` key with some description as below and it will work fine

[image]

**Edit** You should also use the `PhotoLibrary` authorization in proper way as below.

```
@IBAction func importButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({status in
        switch status {
        case .authorized:
            self.imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            self.imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String, kUTTypeImage as String]

            self.present(self.imagePicker,animated: true, completion: nil)
        case .denied:
            print("denied")
        // probably alert the user that they need to grant photo access
        case .notDetermined:
            print("not determined")
        case .restricted:
            print("restricted")
            // probably alert the user that photo access is restricted
        }
    })
}
```